# append(); is not a function.error in console

Tags: javascript

I trying to do simple to do list but append(); is not working and logging an error

**Uncaught TypeError: ul.append is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.takeValue**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
      <input type="text" id="field">
       <button type="submit" id="btn-sub">submit</button>
       <ul class="collection">
         <li class="collection-item">Alvin</li>

    </ul>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

JS

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn-sub');
btn.addEventListener('click', takeValue);

function takeValue(e) {

e.preventDefault();
let con = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
let val = document.getElementById('field').value;
let ul = document.getElementsByClassName('collection');
let li = document.createElement('li');
li.classList.add('collection-item');
li.innerText = val;
ul.append(li);
con.prepend(ul);

}
```

Comment: correct, because you want `appendChild`

Comment: Or alternatively assign `ul` to a jQuery object rather than a NodeList collection.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: ul.appendChild is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.takeValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

**Document.getElementsByClassName()**

> Returns an array-like object of all
>   child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on
>   the document object, the complete document is searched, including the
>   root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName() on any element;
>   it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified
>   root element with the given class names.

so, if you have at least a 'container':

```
let con = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
```

same for your 'collection':

```
let ul = document.getElementsByClassName('collection')[0];
```

then, as you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

> **The Node.appendChild()** 
>   method adds a node to the end of the list of
>   children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference
>   to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its
>   current position to the new position (there is no requirement to
>   remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other
>   node).

```js
function addItem() {
  let con = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
  let val = document.getElementById('field').value;
  let ul = document.getElementsByClassName('collection')[0];
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.classList.add('collection-item');
  li.innerText = val;
  ul.appendChild(li);
  con.prepend(ul);

}
```

```html
<input id="field" value="hello" />
<div class="container">
  <ul class="collection">
  </ul>
</div>
<button onclick="addItem()">hit</button>
```